# Why is this jar on my classpath in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project with some dependencies, and the resulting artifact contains the dependencies as .jar files inside.

I could check the effective pom, but that does not show the actual .jar filenames / classes for the dependencies.

Is there any way to print dependency .jar names?
Is the name always `${artifactId}-${version}.jar`?

Comment: Wrong assumption is that a jar contains the dependencies. This is an exception not the default way. If you create. a shaded/fat jar the jar contains dependencies. By default it does not.

Comment: My artifact is a .war which has a lib folder with the .jar dependencies, not a shaded jar.

Comment: You haven't wrote so... a war is container which combines several jar's inside... So to say something about here it is needed to know the pom file you are using for your war file... All jar's insider a WAR are the dependencies+transitive dependencies given in your pom file...?

Comment: Yes, they are the dependencies+transitive dependencies given in the pom file, maven puts them there.

Comment: Maven does not put anything there. The one who created the pom does this based on the given dependencies...

Comment: `mvn clean package` is run, and based on the pom.xml, maven creates the war with the dependencies inside as jar files. the question is: **given** one jar file from this war, can I trace back the dependency in the pom.xml?

Comment: A jar is produces by a pom.xml file which means you can track back. You might stumble over the issue that your jar file in WAR is a transitive dependency which means you don't see the dependency not directly in your pom file but by using your IDE it easy to find...where the dep is coming from...

Comment: It's a jar from maven central, I can't see its pom directly. I'd like to see why that jar is in my war. Is it a transitive dependency? Is it directly included in my war pom? I don't want to click in an IDE for every dependency, I'd like maven to print it, like the effective pom, just with file names.

Comment: You can take a look via [maven-dependency-plugin:tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) which should print the needed information...

Comment: Can you find out the name of the jar from this dependency tree? Is it always `${artifactId}-${version}.jar` (if the packaging is jar)?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the dependencies used in a Maven build with the Maven Dependency Plugin. To view the dependencies as a list, use:

```
mvn dependency:list
```

A better representation might be the dependency tree, though, as it clearly shows relationships between imported dependency POMs and transitive dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

If you want to see a raw list of the JARs bundled together in your build, you can also use the dependency plugin's `copy-dependencies` goal:

```
$ mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory="\${project.builddir}/bundled-jars" 
$ ls -1 target/bundled-jars
```

Note that the destination is in quotes with the `$` escaped so that it can use the Maven property without invoking shell substitution. You could also just write `-DoutputDirectory=target/bundled-jars`.